# Google Apps scripts: set a defaut answer during the creation of the form

Tags: google-apps-script, default, google-forms

I just started working with google app script in order to create a simple google form composed by several questions with the same structure: image question multiple-choice-item.
In this example I load the images from a google drive

```
 var folder = DriveApp.getFolderById(<gdrive id>);
 var files = folder.getFiles();
 while (files.hasNext()) {
    img = files.next();
    Logger.log(img)
    form.addImageItem()
      .setImage(img)
      .setTitle(img.toString());

    form.addMultipleChoiceItem()
     .setTitle(img.toString())
     .setChoiceValues(['Yes','No', 'Maybe'])
     .setRequired(true);
}
```

There is a way to preselect the all answers to 'No'? In other words, can I preset a choise to a certain value?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the documentation there is currently no defined property for a "default answer" for a `MultipleChoiceItem` or `Choice` item class in a `Form` object. Thus all respondents will have no premarked answers when they open the form.

**References:**

[Class MultipleChoiceItem](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/multiple-choice-item)

[Class Choice](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/choice)